# ssh: connect to host 18.116.70.233 port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, timeout, aws-ec2-instance-connect

When I try to connect ec2 instance using this command from Ubuntu terminal:

```
ssh -i "private_key.pem"  ubuntu@ip_address
```

after taking some times it shows:

> ssh: connect to host 18.116.70.233 port 22: Connection timed out

Note that:

1.firewall is inactive

2.rebooted 3-4 times

3.ssh is installed

but above command didn't work

Comment: you should try telnet <ip_name> 22 first.  It might be that your IP is not whitelisted at instance level.

Comment: What are your instance security group rules?

Comment: UPD: Someone suggested me to change the network operator from Airtel to Grammenphone.I did and worked out. Don't know why!

Answer (score 0):

Review the security group inbound and outbound traffic.
If your computer is on a corporate network or if you are connecting through an internet service provider (ISP). Instead, specify the range of IP addresses used by client computers.
If your security group does not have a rule that allows inbound traffic add  a rule to your security group.

Here's a reference link to
[security group rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#SecurityGroupRules)
[document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html)

Below are steps to connect Amazon EC2 Instance from Ubuntu terminal

-Open terminal and Navigate to the location where you have saved your .pem
key pair file.

-Secure your Key pair file.
sudo chmod 400 abc.pem

-Connect to your instance using IP address.
ssh -i abc.pem ubuntu@IP-address

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).